# Is it possible to test VM/RD application through QTP

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I have installed UFT on Window7 which is my base machine. Now I want test the application which is running on VM/RD through QTP [VM/RD machine has Window7]. 
IS it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I assume "VM" = "Virtual Machine" and "RD" = "Remote Desktop"?  If so...

Technically you can do it, although you will have a horrible experience.  If QTP is not natively running side-by-side with the application, you lose all the context-sensitive automation functionality.  You have to do everything with keystrokes, x-y coordinate-based mouse operations, and bitmap checks.  Install QTP in the same VM or RD and you'll have a better experience.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
Yes , "VM" = "Virtual Machine" and "RD" = "Remote Desktop" 
Currently i have installed UFT on VM but its slow ..So i thought about to install it on base machine

Comment: I suggest a minimum of 2 GB of RAM for your VM, and 4 GB preferred.  QTP uses a lot of RAM, so not allocating enough will cause poor performance.  If you run VM software that allows you to pre-allocate the entire hard drive, that can also help performance (I know VMWare does this, not sure about others).

Comment: I will tell your suggestion to desktop team, lets see.  
I checked my VM configuration, it has got 30 GB RAM & Intel(xenon) 2.00GHz processor  
Thanks

Comment: @onkar ... your VM has that configuration, or the host?  That sounds like your host.  Only the amount of RAM that is allocated to your specific VM will be available for running applications within that VM.  Remote into your VM and check the computer configuration within the virtual environment.